# GNU-Calc: How to change default multiplication symbol (\times) with (\cdot) in LaTeX language display mode

Tags: latex, calc

I'm trying out `calc-embedded` feature to write evaluate/manipulate equations in `calc` then write the output to my `latex`/`org` buffer.

In `calc`, one can change the display mode to LaTeX with <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> (or `calc-latex-language`).
It's so GREAT so convenient.

---

However the `calc-latex-language` in `calc` uses `\times` symbol for the multiplication (e.g. `c \times (a + b)` 1-st row of image below). I much prefer `\cdot` notation (2-nd row of image below).

[image]

---

I can change `\times` with `\cdot` after every time equation is imported from `calc`. However, this seems bit inconvenient.

**Quesiton**:

- Is there way to change the  `calc-latex-language` settings so that that calc uses `\cdot` in the first place instead of `\times`?

---

**Update/Info**:

It might be something to do with below in the `‘calc-lang.el’.`

```
(put 'tex 'math-oper-table
  '( ( "\\hat"    calcFunc-hat     -1  950 )
             ...
     ( "\\times"  *        191 190 )            <-- may be this line????
     ( "*"        *        191 190 )
              ...
```

Being unable to read/write `elisp`, I can do nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized fixing this from the `latex` side (changing symbol behind `\times`) is far more easier than customizing it from `calc`'s LaTeX display mode.

So I asked it from [TeX stack exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/680369/292504) about how to redefine `\times`. Thanks to [Οὖτις's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680371/292504) adding following line to TeX file will make this work.

```
\let\oldtimes\times
\let\times\cdot
```

for Org-File

```
#+begin_export latex
\let\oldtimes\times
\let\times\cdot
#+end_export
```

Now `\times` will symbol behind `\cdot`, and `\oldtimes` will show symbol behind original `\times`.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

Execute the following code so that LaTeX's `\cdot` is interpreted as a multiplication in `calc` (or preferably add it to your `init.el`):

```
;; Interpret LaTeX \cdot as multiplication symbol in calc
(with-eval-after-load 'calc-lang
  (let ((original-value (get 'latex 'math-oper-table)))
    ;; Append a new value to the list
    (put 'latex 'math-oper-table
         (append original-value
                 '(( "\\cdot" * 191 190))))))
```

**Long Answer**

Investigating `calc-lang.el`, the mapping of the LaTeX `\times` argument with `calc`'s multiplication is saved in the `math-oper-table` property of the `tex` package (I left out other mappings):

```
(put 'tex 'math-oper-table
'( ( "\\times"        *        191 190 )))
```

This `math-oper-table` property is then used for the same property of the `latex` package with appending additional property values (again, I left out other mappings and included only one additional LaTeX only mapping).

```
(put 'latex 'math-oper-table
     (append (get 'tex 'math-oper-table)
             '(( "\\Hat"    calcFunc-Hat     -1  950 )
```

We can now append an own entry in the same fashion presented in the first code block. Essentially, we retrieve the current property value, locally bind it using `let` and overwrite the original property with its original value appended by an additional entry. This new entry maps `\cdot` with the multiplication symbol in `calc`. All of this is only executed after the original properties have been created. That is accomplished with `with-eval-after-load`.